# Add row into jqGrid without reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-widgets

I have a jqGrid with "local" source (an array).

I added a button to add a row using this code:

This is the button code:

```
$("#btnAddCategory").button().click(function(event) {
    var newRowId = $.jgrid.randId("new");
    $("#tableCategories").addRowData(newRowId, {
        nome : "prova",
        squadre : 16,
        minutaggio : 40
    }, "last");
});
```

This is the HTML where there are buttons definitions:

```
<form id="frmTCstepCategorie">
    <fieldset class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <legend class="ui-widget">
            Categorie
        </legend>
        <table id="tableCategories">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="categoriesNav">
            <button id="btnAddCategory">
                Aggiungi
            </button>
            <button id="btnDelCategory">
                Rimuovi
            </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It works, but after the insert, the page are reloaded.

How can I add a row without page reloading?

Comment: `addRowData` don't make any reloading of the page. You should search the reason in another part of your code. For example you should verify whether the button click event handler return `false` or you prevent default processing of the click in other way (call of `e.preventDefault` for example).

Comment: may be you have done something in the `editoptions`.

Comment: "_It works, but after the insert, the page are reloaded._"....how? do you get the inserted row or it just resets after loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your button is submit button or some code after adding a row causing page reload.

Try to set type of your button like this

```
type="button"
```

or add

```
return false;
```

at the end of button click handler.

Comment: Now it works. I changed the button definition from `<button>` to `<input type="button" ... >`

Comment: Ok, you can use a <button> element too, but add type="button" to it. Main difference between <button> and <input type="button"> is that <button> allows content inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following line to your jqgrid table:

```
loadonce: true
```